# Add maximise and minimise buttons to Gnome 3.8

Tags: gnome3, menu

I'm currently in the process of trialling Gnomebuntu 13.10 in a virtual machine for web development work with a view to potentially ditching Windows 8.1 for development work in the near future. One of the issues I currently have with Gnome 3.8 is that there are no minimise or maximise buttons by default which screws with my productivity. Is there a way of adding these in? I've already tried the gnome-tweak-tool and there is no clear option to enable this functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

From the `gnome-tweak-tool`, select `Shell` and look for the option `Arrangement of buttons on the titlebar`. By default, it's set to `Close only`, you want to set it to `All`.

If the effects are not immediately apparent, press <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `r` into the command box that appears followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart the Gnome Shell for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: @jezzipin Glad I could help. If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so other people know the problem was solved.

Comment: Will do. Just waiting for the 10 minute timer to count down.

Comment: @jezzipin By the way, I feel sad that you have to transition from Windows to the Gnome Shell. The older version of Gnome was nothing short of glorious. You can still get a taste of it if you choose "Gnome Classic" as your session type during log in.

Comment: I've used the original Gnome back in the day and loved it. Especially the desktop cube!! Unfortunately we have to move with the times. I hate Unity so want to avoid that like the plague.

Comment: @jezzipin Good call. I hate Unity, too.

Comment: @jezzipin in that case I would recommend avoiding Ubuntu altogether. They have an annoying need to brand their GUIs with (IMO) useless and annoying "features" such as the lack of close buttons. Just use a regular Gnome (or, even better `cinnamon`) and a different distro. If you want to have something Ubuntu-style without the silly UI tweaks go for Mint.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the input. I've tried Mint in the past and just didn't like it. I really do prefer Ubuntu in general I just hate Unity. The only other OS I like is Elementary which is beautiful. Unfortunately I haven't tried to get my AMD Catalyst switchable graphics or Steam working under that distro so I'm unsure as to whether I would be able to stick with it long-term.

Comment: @jezzipin Mint _is_ Ubuntu. I recommend you try it again, they have come a long way. Personally, I;ve switched to Mint Debian which is based directly on Debian and has no Ubuntu at all. Most of the things you like about Ubuntu are (probably) from Debian anyway.

Comment: @terdon I know it is. I just don't like it out of the box. I prefer things like the software centre etc